# sql query to delete and return message

Tags: sql-server

I want to write some thing like that query:

```
BEGIN

DECLARE @Unaloacte varchar(200);
DECLARE @Total int;
DECLARE @Flag int;

SET @Unaloacte =( Select count(PD.PropertyDetailId) from PropertyDetail AS PD join 
SiteDetail AS SD ON PD.SiteDetailId=SD.SiteDetailId  Where PD.CustomerId<1 and PD.SiteDetailId=27);

SET @Total= (Select count(PropertyDetailId) as Total_Count from PropertyDetail where SiteDetailId=27) ;

if( @Unaloacte = @Total)
Delete something and display message
print"Delete";
else

print"Not able to delete"

END
```

I hope you understand my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try like this:

```
DECLARE @Msg VARCHAR(200)

if( @Unaloacte = @Total)
BEGIN
BEGIN TRAN

DELETE something 

SELECT @Msg = CAST(@@ROWCOUNT AS VARCHAR(10)) + ' are deleted'
RAISERROR (@Msg, 0, 1) WITH NOWAIT

COMMIT
END

ELSE
BEGIN
SELECT 'Not able to delete'
END
```

Also I would recommend you to use `BEGIN TRAN` and `COMMIT` if you are going to use in Production.

Comment: I want else part aslo. If not able to delete then display message.

Comment: @DevelopShailendra:- Added that. Please check.

Comment: Invalid column name "Not able to delete"

Comment: @DevelopShailendra:- My mistake. Use the single quotes instead of double quotes. Updated my answer. Please check now.

Comment: If this answer helped you please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).  Accepting answers rewards the contributor and helps others, with a similar issue, to find a working solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can check this by USING `@@ROWCOUNT` and `SET NOCOUNT ON`

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
DELETE FROM TableName
IF @@ROWCOUNT > 0
  PRINT 'Record Deleted'
ELSE 
  PRINT 'Record Not Deleted'
```

Here `SET NOCOUNT ON` is used since we dont want to see number of rows affected message.